# How to make PlantUML state diagrams cleaner?

Tags: uml, clion, plantuml

Is there a way to make State diagrams more organized and clean in PlantUML easily?
My fear was the more stuff I add, the more convoluted it becomes and it did happen.

I tried using `skinparam linetype ortho` setting which made things a bit better but still not enough. Should be using a different type rather than state diagrams which may fit in well? I'm new to PlantUML and still exploring the options.

```
scale 350 width


state A               #khaki
state B           #BUSINESS
state C         #bisque
state D       #APPLICATION
state E          #IndianRed
state F   #MediumTurquoise
state G             #Salmon
state E      #HoneyDew
state G          #PaleTurquoise
state H     #Aqua

state JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED      <<join>>
state JOIN_STATE_FAILED         <<join>>
state JOIN_STATE_STARTUP_REQ    <<join>>
state JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN      <<join>>

[*] --> A
A --> B

B --> C
C -[#Red]-> JOIN_STATE_FAILED
C -[#IndianRed]-> JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED
C --> D

C --> JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN
D --> JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN
F --> JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN
G --> JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN
H --> JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN


D --> F
D --> D

D -[#Red]-> JOIN_STATE_FAILED
'D --> G : EV_MODULE_STARTUP_REQUEST fails
D -[#IndianRed]-> JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED
'D --> E : EV_MODULE_STARTUP_REQUEST timeout

F --> G
F -[#Red]-> JOIN_STATE_FAILED
F -[#IndianRed]-> JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED

G --> H
G -[#Red]-> JOIN_STATE_FAILED
G -[#IndianRed]-> JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED

E -[#Crimson]-> G
E -[#FireBrick]-> E

E --> A

JOIN_STATE_UNDEFINED -[#IndianRed]-> E
JOIN_STATE_FAILED -[#Red]-> G
JOIN_STATE_SHUT_DOWN --> E

@enduml
```

[image]

Comment: What would you call more organised and clean ? it’s a complex diagram in which it seems impossible to avoid crossing lines. The question if whether you need the junctions, and if yes, if it wouldn’t be better represented with an activity diagram (the arrows becomming the actions that  make the state change)

Comment: like you said, clearer to understand and visualize rather than spending a lot of time following along the lines to see the connection between the states..  and what junctions are you referring to?

Comment: sorry, I mean your [join pseudostates](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/state-machine-diagrams.html#join-pseudostate): as I do not see orthogonal regions, I wonder what their purpose is.

Comment: Ah, just to indicate all the lines going into it end up in a common state, rather than each line going into the next state separately

Comment: Why not label your transitions? When I see all the shutdowns going to E, I realize C, D, F, G, H all have an event going there. If you grouped them inside another state, then you just have a single shutdown transition leaving that (compound) state (which I think means all those states inside transition to E on a shutdown). Would that not simplify some?